# Class "illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage" not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an application in laravel and when I perform the test with insomnia (post), it presents the following  **"Class illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage" not found** .
follow my code below

**WarningController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use App\Models\Warning;
use App\Models\Unit;

class WarningController extends Controller
{

    public function addWarningFile(Request $request)
    {
        $array = ['error' => ''];

        $validator = validator::make($request->all(), [
            'photo' => 'required|file|mimes:jpg,png'
        ]);

        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            $file = $request->file('photo')->store('public');
            $array['photo'] = asset(Storage::url($file));
        } else {
            $array['error'] = $validator->errors()->first();
            return $array;
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

**Validator.php**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;


class Validator extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'validator';
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are using the lower character "i" instead of "I", use ```Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator```

Comment: Also when you'r using Laravel Facades you can just call it `\Storage` (slash before classname) in your code without needing to write `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` at begging of the PHP File.

Comment: Thank you for your help Yehor Smoliakov.